# Isolated Point Singularities on Curves

Tags: partial-derivative, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves, singularity

I know that a curve $C: f(x, y) = 0$ is singular provided there is a point $(x_0, y_0) \in C$ for which $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0)=0.$$ However, suppose the singular point is an isolated point. For example, the point $(-1,0)$ on the curve $$C:y^2=x^3-3x-2=(x-2)(x+1)^2.$$ Both partials are $0$ when evaluated at $(-1, 0)$, but if the definition of a partial derivative is defined using a limit and the curve $C$ is not defined in any neighborhood around the point $(-1, 0)$, don't the partials fail to exist? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The curve is defined at the point, it just singular there, so I don't understand what you mean by that? In the context of algebraic geometry, it's normally the case that any "derivatives" you take are purely formal (although the ideas do line up) so there's no limit floating around anywhere. If you wish to compute the "slope(s)" via limits, in fact this is sometimes possible (e.g., $y^2 = x^2(x + 1)$ has slopes at the node - and this even has interesting arithmetic applications in the theory of elliptic curves).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see your point now - the point is that the ideas only line up when your field is algebraically closed, so over $\mathbb{C}$ the singular point will not be isolated (since $C$ is irreducible) and you can use limits. However over $\mathbb{R}$ the construction remains formal

Comment: $y^2=((x+1)-3)(x+1)^2$ around $(-1,0)$ has tangent cone $y^2+3(x+1)^2=0,$ which is a pair of complex lines meeting in the singular real point $(-1,0)$.